# node.js - run app, when JSON config file was loaded from file

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, configuration-files

Since fs.read/write functions are async, I wonder whats the proper way to implement, that in the beginning the webapp continues to run, when the settings JSON obj has been loaded from a .json file.

If done a fileJSON.js module to do the save and load from the .json file, but how do I use it properly to achieve what I described:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {

    save: function(path, json, callback) {
        if(typeof json === "object"){
            json = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
        }
        if(typeof json === "string"){
            return fs.writeFile(path, json, 'utf8', callback);
        }else{
            return error("argument not an obj or a string");
        }
    },

    load: function(path, callback) {
        fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                return "shit happened - see log";
            } else {
                let obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
                callback(obj);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it to run on startup (e.g. a config file that you don't expect to reload without restarting the application), the easiest thing is to just `require` it.

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

it runs synchronously and caches the results in the npm cache for as long as the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

Storing configuration in environment is part of  [twelve factor app](https://12factor.net/config)  so you might want to  use [Dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package. It is used for exporting configuration variables to environment. Just create `.env` file in root of yout project.

```
// .env
HOST_ADDRESS=localhost:9000
```

Run your script with require option like so:

```
node -r dotenv/config index.js
```

You can access the variable like that:

```
console.log(proccess.env.HOST_ADDRESS)
```